# c++ convert from new to instance

Tags: c++

There is a problem that confuses me

I created a new variable

```
Foo *a=new Foo();
```

Then I declared an Instance variable

```
Foo b;
```

Now I want to convert the new variable to the instance variable, so I did

```
b.setValue0(a->getValue0());
b.setValue1(a->getValue1());
b.setValue2(a->getValue2());
```

Is there an easier faster way to do this?

Comment: you can't just declare b and expect the variable to become an instance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the copy constructor:

```
Foo b(*a);
```

assuming of course that copying the object is permitted.

Answer (score 1):

> *"Is there an easier faster way to do this?"*

You can declare an assignment operator for `Foo`

```
 Foo& operator=(const Foo&);
```

Thus you can write

```
 b = *a;
```

---

The other option is to provide a copy constructor

```
 Foo(const Foo&);
```

This allows to initialize `b` directly

```
 Foo b(*a);
```

---

You should note that the compiler will automatically generate these operations for you, unless you declare any of these your own, or declare special constructors with paraneters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use copy constructor with a reference to a const parameter. It is const to guarantee that the copy constructor doesn't change it.

```
class Foo{
    public:
        . . .
        // copy constructor
        Foo(const Foo &b) 
        {
           value0 = b.value0;
           value1 = b.value1;
        }
}

//=== file main_program.cpp ====================================
. . .
Foo fooObj;                        // calls default constructor
Foo anotherFooObj = fooObj;        // calls copy constructor.
```